# Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I am trying to implement a modal dialog by using jquery in my application. It should work by popping out a modal dialog to display a web page (url) once I clicked on a button. But I keep getting JavaScript runtime error:

> Object doesn't support property or method "dialog" error in the line `$("#dialog").dialog("open")`.

I have already included those jquery scripts in my application. I am using scripts from **jquery-ui-1.12.1.zip**.
Here is my code for your reference.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnProdHierarchy").click( function() {
                $("#dialog").load(PMASTERLINK, function() {
                    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                    return false;
                }
                )
            })
        });
</script>


<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"></div>
<input id="btnProdHierarchy" type="button" value="Product Master"  accesskey="H" />
```

Please give me a hand in solving this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Why have you appended `jquery-ui` twice??

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnProdHierarchy").click( function() {
            $("#dialog").load(PMASTERLINK, function() {
                $("#dialog").dialog().dialog("open");
                return false;
            })
        })
    });
</script>


<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"></div>
<input id="btnProdHierarchy" type="button" value="Product Master" accesskey="H" />
```

I replaced `PMASTERLINK` with something else, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Your dialog loading is wrong. try read jquery-ui documentation first. also in your code "PMASTERLINK" is undefined!

the dialog should be define like :

```
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,      
});
```

and your button should be like :

```
$( "#dialogBtn" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

thats it!

HTML :

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
 <p>Your Dialog Text</p>
</div>

<button id="dialogBtn">Open Dialog</button>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/ebgkmw79/1/